# Universal Image Loader - big memory consumption

Tags: android, memory, android-listview, universal-image-loader

Thing is, my application uses about 80mb and tend to crash and run out of memory on older devices. I think I've done what I could: configured universal to low consumption and implemented viewholder. As described in previous posts on StackOverflow, and at the https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info

My application consists of a ListView with 10 images (each images is loaded from server, and is about 100kb size, 1000x1000 pixels (but varies from image to image)).

Now I tend to think, that I might have implemented something wrong in my code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageObject>{
    private List<ImageObject> images;
    private Context context;
    private int resourceID;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceID, List<ImageObject> images) {
        super(context, resourceID, images);

        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.resourceID = resourceID;

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .delayBeforeLoading(0)
            .build();

        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPoolSize(2)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .build();

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(resourceID, null);   

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            holder.hasAnimated = false;
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        ImageObject image = images.get(position);
        if(image != null){
            ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(holder.image, false);

            if(!holder.hasAnimated){
                imageLoader.displayImage(image.getUrl(), imageAware, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.animation);
                        holder.image.setAnimation(animation);
                        animation.start();
                    }
                });
                holder.hasAnimated = true;
            }else{
                imageLoader.displayImage(image.getUrl(), imageAware);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
          ImageView image;
          Boolean hasAnimated;
    }
}
```

Are there anything obvious, that I did wrong? Or obviously for improving?

**Edit:** And why is EXACTLY_STRETCHED consuming more than EXACTLY? Seems like some images doesn't fill out when just using EXACTLY (Using  android:scaleType="centerCrop" in ImageView).

Thanks and best regards.